# Table data structure in C++ using a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vectors

I'm learning C++, and now I have to implement a table data structure.

I don't know a lot about C++, so I have implemented using a vector of vectors. To access the rows of the tables I have defined eight constants with the name of the planets. And, to access the columns I have defined other nine constants.

This is my code:

```
static const int Mercury = 0;
static const int Venus = 1;
static const int Earth = 2;
static const int Mars = 3;
static const int Jupiter = 4;
static const int Saturn = 5;
static const int Uranus = 6;
static const int Neptune = 7;

static const int PeriodOrbit = 0;
static const int LogintudeAtEpoch = 1;
static const int LongitudeOfPerihelion = 2;
static const int EccentricityOfOrbit = 3;
static const int SemiMajorAxisOrbit = 4;
static const int OrbitalInclination = 5;
static const int LongitudeOfAscendingNode = 6;
static const int AngularDiameterAt1AU = 7;
static const int VisualMagnitudeAt1AU = 8;

static const std::vector<std::vector<double>> ElementsPlanetaryOrbits = {
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }
};
```

With the planet's constants I will get the row for that planet. One I have its row, I will use the other nine constants to get the value that I need (i.e. the period of the orbit).

Is there a better way to do it?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using `static const` because the data in the table don't change. I have not said it before because I thought that was understood by `static const`.

Comment: How about `struct PlanetData { double orbit; double longetudeAtEpoch; /*..*/};`?

Comment: Good first attempt from. :-)

Comment: You got a lot of answers saying to use a vector of structures rather than a table, but that defeats the point of the assignment.  So, I submit that the example is not a good use of a table.  You want both dimensions to be something that you would naturally index, not be separate kinds of data.  E.g. golf scores per hole per player.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the Right Data Structure

First, since you have a fixed number of parameters in every row, consider defining it as a `struct`, with fields instead of column indices.  Then the fields can have different types, and you cannot pass your structure an invalid column index.  As these are compile-time constants, you will be able to declare them `constexpr`, which lets the compiler optimize calculations that it can compute at compile time.  It’s faster to access an array of arrays or structures than a vector of vectors, too, and takes less memory to store and less time to allocate.

A `constexpr` array of `struct` is probably the right approach for this problem, but you can keep on reading if you want some more  alternatives to a vector of vectors.

A vector of vectors is very rarely the data structure you want.  A pointer to an array of pointers is even less so, which is why it’s so unfortunate that every beginner learns about `char **argv` first.

Generally, vectors of vectors have high overhead and poor locality of reference relative to vectors of arrays or arrays of arrays, so they perform worse.

If you have a **rectangular** array, that is, a table where the rows are all the same length, but where you might need to add more planets, you have several good options:

- An array of arrays, if it’s fixed-size.  These can be C-style arrays with `[]` or `std::array`.
- A vector of arrays, if you need to be able to add rows.
- For sparse matrices, a format such as compressed sparse row (more complicated for a beginner)
- A `Matrix` class that stores the entire table in one linear vector and accepts two-dimensional indices.  This would let you write something like `Matrix<double> a(4, 4); a(1, 1) = 1.0;`.

The basic skeleton of a container like that might look like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdexcept>

template<class T>
  class Matrix{
      public:
      Matrix();
      Matrix( size_t, size_t );
      // You probably want to default copy, move and assign.
      T& operator() ( size_t, size_t );
      const T& operator() ( size_t, size_t ) const;

      private:
      size_t row_size, num_columns;
      std::vector<T> private_buffer;
  };

template<class T>
  T& Matrix<T>::operator() ( const size_t i, const size_t j )
  {
    if (i >= num_columns || j >= row_size){
      throw std::out_of_range("Matrix subscripts out of range.");
    }

    return private_buffer[ i*row_size + j ];
  }
```

What if you really do need a **ragged array**, where the rows are different lengths?  In most use cases, you can still use another structure than a vector of vectors.  For example, you might lay out your rows consecutively in memory, storing the starting-point of each vector in an index vector.  You can then easily construct a subrange or view (different names for the same thing) of a row from the starting point of your row and the next row.

There, the skeleton of an implementation might look like:

```
template<class T> class RaggedArray {
    public:
    RaggedArray();
    RaggedArray( size_t, size_t );
    // You probably want to default copy, move and assign.
    T& operator() ( size_t, size_t );
    const T& operator() ( size_t, size_t ) const;

    private:
    std::vector<T> private_buffer;
    std::vector<size_t> index_vector;
};

template<class T>
  T& RaggedArray<T>::operator() ( const size_t i, const size_t j )
  {
    if (i >= index_vector.size() ||
        index_vector[i] + j >= index_vector[i+1]){
      throw std::out_of_range("Matrix subscripts out of range.");
    }

    return private_buffer[ index_vector[i] + j ];
  }
```

This lays out the data consecutively in memory, so you have none of the overhead of an extra layer of dereferencing, locality of reference, and more straightforward copy/move/compare/etc. semantics.  The major disadvantage here is if you have to resize a row other than the last.  Since the rows are laid out consecutively in memory, this data structure forces you to shift everything after that row in memory, a costly operation.

### Things Other than That

Although compilers are smart enough to optimize your `static const` declarations, you probably want your symbolic names for indices to be an `enum`.  Then, your interface can accept a `planet` and a `planet_info`.  Not only will this prevent you from accidentally passing in an invalid value, the compiler will then catch if you mix up your row and column number.

Constants known at compile time should be declared `constexpr` when possible.  You should use `const` for data that must be computed at runtime, but will not change thereafter, such as `const auto howMarsIsDoingToday = haveJamesWebbTelescopeLookAt(mars);`.

You could, again, make the set of planet information a `struct` with fields rather than a vector or array with named indices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data in the table will never change. I only need to access it using the constants declared before it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a vector of vectors is the way to go.

if we assume each row is the information about a planet. Then each row is structured data. So we should use a structure to represent the data:

```
struct PlanetData
{
    double periodOrbit;
    double logintudeAtEpoch;
    double longitudeOfPerihelion;
    double eccentricityOfOrbit;
    double semiMajorAxisOrbit;
    double orbitalInclination;
    double longitudeOfAscendingNode;
    double angularDiameterAt1AU;
    double visualMagnitudeAt1AU;
};
```

So now we could have a vector of this structured data:

```
static constexpr int CountOfPlanets = 8;
std::vector<PlanetData>   elementsPlanetaryOrbits(CountOfPlanets);
```

Alternatively since you don't look like you need to resize the number of planets (or you only need to do that after re-compiling (its not dynamic)) you could use a std::array rather than std::vector.

```
std::array<PlanetData, CountOfPlanets>   elementsPlanetaryOrbits;
```

---

I like the idea of being able to index the `elementsPlanetaryOrbits` by a specific name `Mercury` as that seems important to make sure we don't have accidents and you have done that using your constants.

```
static constexpr int Mercury = 0;
static constexpr int Venus = 1;
static constexpr int Earth = 2;
static constexpr int Mars = 3;
static constexpr int Jupiter = 4;
static constexpr int Saturn = 5;
static constexpr int Uranus = 6;
static constexpr int Neptune = 7;
// Notice the use of `constexpr` rather than `const`.
```

But here you can index into the `elementsPlanetaryOrbits` by an integer and that seems like you can have some accidents. You want to try and design your code so it can not be used incorrectly.

So I like the idea of using a map (or unordered map) and specifying an enum as the key. This will prevent you from accidentally using an integer.

```
enum class Planets {Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune};
std::map<Planets, PlanetData>    elementsPlanetaryOrbits;
```

OK. Now I have to point out that there are some disadvantages to maps (locality) is not good access time is always going to be slower than a vector. But you should weigh the use case of correctness against these factors (only you have enough information to make the correct choice). Personally I am always going to go for correctness and preventing mistakes first then optimize for speed when I prove to myself it needs that extra oomf (though that is a controversial opinion in the C++ world).  :-)

I would start with the `std::map` as above, but if I need to improve the speed I would change to a std::vector but wrap it in structure to give accesses via the enum.

```
// Version 1
using PlanerHolder = std::map<Planets, PlanetData>;

// Now in the future I discover that map is not suffecient.
// Version 2
class PlanerHolder
{
    std::vector<PlanetData>    data;
    public:
        PlanerHolder()
            : data(CountOfPlanets)
        {}
        PlanetData& operator[](Planets index)
        {
            return data[static_cast<int>(index)];
        }
        // any other members you need.
};
```

---

Note: I have implemented PlanetData as a simple property bag (a structure with some unconnected data). You may want to upgrade this to a class with proper constructor and appropriate methods that support your use case (but please avoid get/set methods in preference of methods that do meaningful tasks).

Actually the first thing I would do is add a constructor so that the members are at least correctly initialized to zero. Though if you only use them in standard containers this is not required as the containers will do this for you.

---

```
// Version 1 Initialization:
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct PlanetData
{
    double periodOrbit;
    double logintudeAtEpoch;
    double longitudeOfPerihelion;
    double eccentricityOfOrbit;
    double semiMajorAxisOrbit;
    double orbitalInclination;
    double longitudeOfAscendingNode;
    double angularDiameterAt1AU;
    double visualMagnitudeAt1AU;
};

enum class Planet {Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune};
using PlanerHolder = std::map<Planet, PlanetData const>;
PlanerHolder ElementsPlanetaryOrbits{
    {Planet::Mercury, { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }},
    {Planet::Venus,   { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }},
    {Planet::Earth,   { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }},
    {Planet::Mars,    { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }},
    {Planet::Jupiter, { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }},
    {Planet::Saturn,  { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }},
    {Planet::Uranus,  { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }},
    {Planet::Neptune, { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 }}
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << ElementsPlanetaryOrbits[Planet::Earth].orbitalInclination << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data in the table will never change. I only need to access it using the constants declared before it.

Comment: I don’t think you need to abandon the more-efficient array or map data structure here. The `enum` will automatically convert to an index. You might also implement a type-safe `constexpr double orbitPeriod(planet)` functions, etc., that look up the data in one or more `constexpr` arrays. Or, instead of an array with named indices, you could have nine named `constexpr` arrays.  If you do want a map, it should be an `unordered_map`, which would be implemented as a hash table with constant-time access.

Comment: @Davislor I know the enum will convert to int thats the problem. I want to make sure that I can only use the enum to access the planets.

Comment: @Davislor Constant time does not mean faster. hash maps have a large overhead and for this small number of items that overhead way overwhelms the small access time of log(n).

Comment: @VansFannel That fact that everything is constant does not change anything I have said above.

Comment: @MartinYork Right, I figured you wanted type-safety. That’s why I suggested dropping the array entirely and having `mercuryInfo.orbitalPeriodDays`, `venusInfo.OrbitalPeriodDays`, etc. (although that doesn't let you iterate through the planets). Another would be `double orbitalPeriodDays(planet_it)`. Another would be wrapping the internal array in an interface that accepted `planetDB[mars].orbitalPeriodDays`.

Comment: @MartinYork It’s likely that the hash function on small integers would be fast, but in any case, you can use `.at` on a STL array or container to get bounds-checking.

Comment: @Davislor: Big O notation does not apply here. n is fixed (at 8) even if it does expand the arguable range of n is trivially small. The only question is the cost of hash lookup quicker than tree lookup (for very small n) given the overheads of each. The only way to find out is time.

Comment: @MartinYork That’s a fair point, although the implication is that overhead doesn’t matter for such a small set and we should do what’s most convenient. I think that’s probably a `constexpr std::array` and using `.at(planet_jupiter)` to do bounds checking. The optimal approach would be to add an overloaded lookup function that takes `planet_id` and calls the built-in `[]` operator of the array or vector. You could use many other kinds of data structures as well, but generally I use unordered maps for unordered keys.

Comment: @Davislor `we should do what’s most convenient` I would phrase that as `optimize design for correctness first, then look to optimize for speed when you can show it is an issue`

Comment: @Davislor Also the actual size of a hash table is huge in comparison to a tree especially when 99% if it is not being used. So you are optimizing for speed without regard for optimizing for space.

Comment: @Davislor Note: I already talked about using a wrapper: see `Version 2` above.

Comment: @MartinYork Great!

Comment: @MartinYork Planet Earth will have only five elements, and the rest of the planets nine.